# Is it permissible to reheat rice on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, cooking-bishul, kitniyos-semigrain-legume, orach-chaim

According to Halacha is it permissible to reheat already cooked rice on Shabbat? Would it depend on if it is reheated in a kli sheini or a kli rishon or would that not make a difference either way?

Comment: Why would it be different than anything else?

Comment: @Chatzkel maybe because rice cooking is bishul and the dry reheating is afiya?

Comment: @Chatzkel it actually is a member of a rich debate over whether rice is considered a solid dry food, which has the status of being a kli rishon, or whether it is considered a fluid food, which does not halachically retain heat if placed in a kli sheni. Note that this idea of the hot dry solid food remaining a kli rishon itself is not accepted by the Rama, but the Taz and Shach both agree with it in comments to YD 105:2. I think it's the PMG who differentiates between solid rice and rice that is in a broth, noting how the determination may decide its status as a kli rishon.